# Not sure how to parse this PHP/JSON object in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

So from what I understand, because I created a JSON object in PHP using `json_encode` and then used `echo` to display it, I can access it directly as an object in JS, like this

```
.done(function(response) {
    var result = response;
    $(result).hide().prependTo('#messages').fadeIn('slow');
});`
```

However, how do I access the data within the object? My object contains `error` which will be either true or false, and `error_message` while contains the errors formatted as `<li>error</li>`

PHP returns this - `{"error":true,"error_messages":" <li>Name too short (minimum of 4 characters)<\/li> <li>Name too short (minimum of 4 characters)<\/li>"}`

Comment: How does your JSON output look like? Install Firebug and paste a sample output...

Comment: response.error and response.error_messages will store these values

Comment: `response.error`, `response.error_message `

Comment: @cantsay: To improve your question, use the "edit" link under the question, not comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your server returns the correct `Content-Type` header (`application/json`), jQuery will parse the response for you and give you an object, which you can use like this:

```
console.log(response.error_messages); // "<li>Name too short...
```

If your server does not return the correct `Content-Type` header, you can force the issue by supplying

```
dataType: "json"
```

in your [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) call.

Either way, the JSON you've quoted in the comment on your question is valid.

So it may be that you want:

```
if (response.error) {
    $(response.error_messages).hide().prependTo('#messages').fadeIn('slow');
}
else {
    // whatever you show when it's successful
}
```

But note that `#messages` **must** be a `menu`, `ul`, or `ol` element, since your `error_message` defines an [`li` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element).

Comment: I don't know if anyone agrees, but I think always explicitly setting `dataType` to what you expect it to be is a good idea, so that it's always parsed correctly. Then again, the better way may be to never do that, so you ensure your server is configured correctly (but then you're leaving possible failures)

Comment: @Ian: Yeah, it's a judgment call. I lean toward making sure the server is sending back the right information, so all links in the chain (proxies and whatnot) have good information to work with. This is really easy with most server-side technologies (including PHP).

Comment: thanks, but I tried `alert(result.error_messages)` and it says undefined

Comment: @cantsay: Okay. So what do you see when you walk through this with the debugger? `alert` is not a very useful debugging tool. Your browser has a debugger built into it, with powerful tools for stepping through your code statement by statement, using breakpoints, etc. What do you see when you do that?

Comment: okay, did `console.log(response)` and it shows `TypeError: e is undefined` (jquery.min line 4) then below it shows the response from PHP which I added to my original question with `()` around it. I tried changing `error_messages` to "test" as well

Comment: @cantsay: There is no reference to `e` in the code in your question. Rather than using `console.log`, again, what do you see when you use the debugger built into your browser? Set a breakpoint, single-step through the code, inspect variables...

Comment: hi, I managed to get it working now. I think I had been passing back some HTML with the JSON data, but because it was commented it didn't show on the PHP side

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use it as an object like normal.  E.g:

```
result.error; // true or false
result.error_messages; // the error messages
```

You may need to parse it, but jQuery (which it looks like you're using) may do that for you.  If it doesn't, use `JSON.parse`:

```
var myobj = JSON.parse(result);
```